# Appending date and time stamp while using json.dump?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, logging

Hi i am currently dumping the output of image matrix per frame in the following manner.  I

```
with open(os.path.join('logs', 'frame_{0}_keypoints.json'.format(str(frame_number).zfill(12))).format(frame_dict), 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

With this i can get, `json` files per frame , with the format `frame_000000000001_keypoints` , I was wondering if there is a way to append time stamp to the logs ?? for example like `20190607T220005` `YearMonthDayTimeinHoursMinutesSeconds` ??

Comment: Which logs? And what do timestamps have to do with image-processing (given the tags)?

Comment: add `import time; time.asctime()` to your dict.

Comment: Do you mean that i should append it ?

Comment: @timtensor Do you want to add a new property to `my_dict`? A timestamp?

Comment: Not to the `my_dict` but to the name of the files output per frame . The nomenclature of the file name

Comment: Ok. So you can ignore my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assume you want to add a timestamp to 'my_dict'.

```
import json
import time


class TimeStampAdderEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        obj['timestamp'] = time.time()
        return json.JSONEncoder().encode(obj)


my_dict = {'key': 3}
my_dict_as_str = json.dumps(my_dict, cls=TimeStampAdderEncoder)
print(my_dict_as_str)
```

output

```
{"key": 3, "timestamp": 1561542873.109698}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a output .json file with this format `frame_ 20190607T220005_keypoints`, you can use :

```
import datetime 
now = datetime.datetime.now()   

now_isoFormat = now.isoformat() # GET - 2019-06-26T09:20:30.943730

now_custom_isoFormat = "{YEAR}{MONTH}{DAY}T{HOUR}{MINUTES}{SECONDS}".format(
    YEAR=now.year,
    MONTH=now.month,
    DAY=now.day,
    HOUR=now.hour,
    MINUTES=now.minute,
    SECONDS=now.second) # GET - 2019626T092030

with open(os.path.join('logs', 'frame_{0}_keypoints.json'.format(now_custom_isoFormat)).format(frame_dict), 'w') as outfile:
       json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

If you wish to keep the frame number :

```
with open(os.path.join('logs', 'frame_{date}_keypoints_{frame}.json'
        .format(date=now_custom_isoFormat,
                frame=str(frame_number).zfill(12)))
                  .format(frame_dict), 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks ! is it possible to append the frame number ? Then i can have the format
`frame_ 20190607T220005_keypoints_(per_frame) `. Which i do it from 
`frame_{0}_keypoints.json'.format(str(frame_number).zfill(12))).format(frame_dict)`

Comment: Thank you ! it is what i wanted

Comment: Hi Frank , I will change the question tag to solved